# Alexa CRM how can i add data to different entities

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, alexacrm-toolkit

I'm using https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit to send data from a form to an entity in CRM.

With normal fields it's okay but when I want to add 'new_produit_demande' it's gives error because that field is assigned to another entity ('new_produituic') and ('contact')

Any suggestions?

This is some code and it's not working.

```
<?php 
 require 'autoload.php' ;
 use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Client as OrganizationService;
 use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Settings;
 $options = [
 'serverUrl' => 'https://xxxxx',
              'username' => 'xxxx',
              'password' => 'xxxx',
              'authMode' => 'xxx',

];
$serviceSettings = new Settings( $options );
$service = new OrganizationService( $serviceSettings );
$guid = 'd5bac140-b68b-e911-80cc-005056aa3849';
  $contact = $service->entity('contact');
$contact->firstname='product1';
$contact->new_produit_demande = new EntityReference('new_produituic',$guid);
$contactId = $contact->create();
```

The error:

> Fatal error: Class 'EntityReference' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ccr\test.php on line 29

Comment: why post "some code" and not a complete working example? Please do. Any relevant error/event log info to share? Post it.

Comment: ah sorry , if you need more informations tell me please

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the below namespace:

```
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Entity\EntityReference;
```